# How to retrieve subcategory data from json

Tags: java, json, android-studio

First of all sorry if the term **subcategory** is not the right one, I did not know what to call it

I'm trying to retrieve the data present in `data` but I can't.

My Json

```
{
  "server": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "Franky",
          "premium": true,
          "total": 148
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Main.java

```
private void getData() {
  String url = "https://api.example.com/key=XXXX";

  JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { 
          try { 
              JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server");
              for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject server = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                  String name = data.getString("name");
                  boolean premium = data.getBoolean("premium");
                  int total = data.getInt("total");

                  UsersModel usersModel = new UsersModel(name, premium, total);
                  usersModelList.add(usersModel);

                  UsersAdapter usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), usersModelList);
                  recyclerUsers.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
              }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          error.printStackTrace();
      }
  });

  requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

I don't get a crash but I find these error lines in logcat

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for name
org.json.JSONException: No value for premium
org.json.JSONException: No value for total
```

If you have a solution!

Comment: What does "but I can't" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Does that compile? The variable `data` isn't defined. You seem to have left out the part that reads the `data` item in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON, the `data` property is also an array, so you need to access it as such:

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject serverItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONArray dataArray = serverItem.getJSONArray("data");
  for (int j = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject data = dataArray.getJSONObject(j);
     String name = data.getString("name");
     boolean premium = data.getBoolean("premium");
     int total = data.getInt("total");
     UsersModel usersModel = new UsersModel(name, premium, total);
     usersModelList.add(usersModel);
     UsersAdapter usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), usersModelList);
     recyclerUsers.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.octomix.josson/josson

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.20'

-------------------------------------------------

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString("{\n" +
        "  \"server\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"data\": [\n" +
        "        {\n" +
        "          \"name\": \"Franky\",\n" +
        "          \"premium\": true,\n" +
        "          \"total\": 148\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      ]\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ]\n" +
        "}");
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data")); // -> [{"name":"Franky","premium":true,"total":148}]
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data.name")); // -> ["Franky"]
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data.premium")); // -> [true]
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data.total")); // -> [148]
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data[0]")); // -> {"name":"Franky","premium":true,"total":148}
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data[0].name")); // -> "Franky"
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data[0].premium")); // -> true
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data[0].total")); // -> 148
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data.name[0]")); // -> "Franky"
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data.premium[0]")); // -> true
System.out.println(josson.getNode("server.data.total[0]")); // -> 148
```